# Does Typescript take into account condition checking?

Tags: typescript

I have this weird TypeScript compile warning that I cannot get rid of, although I think it shouldn't even be there...

These are the interfaces:

```
interface Props {
  tasks: TaskType[]
}

interface State {
  completed: boolean
  selectedTask?: TaskType
}
```

This is the initiation of state - I start with `undefined`, but in other places in my code an actual value of type `TaskType` can be assigned:

```
class TaskBlock extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  state = {
    completed: false,
    selectedTask: undefined
  }
```

This is where I get the warning in my `render` method:

```
const {selectedTask} = this.state
...
const isSelected = selectedTask && selectedTask.id === task.id
```

The warning message is here:
[image]

As you can see, just before the `selectedTask.id` statement I am checking that `selectedTask` is NOT undefined. But TypeScript says the object is possibly 'undefined'. Doesn't make sense...

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Could you try to expand your example a little? Maybe a full component that demonstrates the problem. A few details are missing here that make it hard to see what's causing it.

Comment: Hi @MadaraUchiha. The component is quite big and complex, so I wanted to avoid pasting all the irrelevant bits. However, I have added also the interface for `props` as well as how I'm asserting the types on the component.

Comment: I just noticed that if I assert `State` type on state additionally like so - `state: State = { completed: false, selectedTask: undefined }` - then the warning goes away. Any idea why the `React.Component<Props, State>` assertion wasn't sufficient?

Comment: You don't need to paste the entire component here, try to reproduce the problem with a simpler component (say, just a simple state and a simple render function). If it doesn't reproduce, it will give you a clue that something else is wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`undefined` is not a valid value to assign to `selectedTask`. Your `State` interface is as follows

```
interface State {
  completed: boolean
  selectedTask?: TaskType
}
```

This means that a `TaskType` may be assigned to `selectedTask`, or `selectedTask` may be missing altogether. But assinging `undefined` to it is an error (Unless `TaskType` itself is `Something | undefined`).

Change your interface to `selectedTask: TaskType | undefined`, this makes it so the `selectedTask` key must exist on the state object, but the value might also be `undefined`.

Comment: Aaah, I see, so `selectedTask?: TaskType` was after all NOT equivalent to `selectedTask: TaskType | undefined`. Thanks for your help!